# Sharepoint Designer 2007 Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-workflow

In Sharepoint designer 2007, I am creating a workflow where I am trying to use 'collect data from a user' for multiple users.  In my document library, I have a list name field.  That list name field ties to a list which has between 1-15 users in the associated list.  I only need to collect data from user for those users in the list that are not null/empty.  I would also like to collect data from the users at the same time (parallel).

It appears you can only use parallel within one workflow step.  Within one workflow step, it doesn't appear that you can set multiple conditions/actions.

What I need to do is this:

Condition 1:  If variable:reviewer1 is not empty
Action 1:     Collect Document Review from variable:reviewer1 (output to ...)
Condition 2:  If variable:reviewer2 is not empty
Action 2:     Collect Document Review from variable:reviewer2 (output to...)

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It'll be tedious, but I'd suggest creating N steps (where N = the number of parallel tasks you want)

Each step will generally do the following:

1. Check if the current reviewer field is empty (if so, skip to the next step)
2. Create a new "Task" item in a (task) List
3. Send an email to the person you assigned the task to

Then you'll need to somehow stop your workflow until all of the tasks have been completed. This part gets a bit trickier, but do some searches on creating a State Machine workflow in SharePoint Designer and you'll be on the right track.

Really though, this sounds like a workflow that's too complex for SPD. Use Visual Studio or some 3rd-party workflow solution if at all possible.